# Creating files based on column from 2D Matrix - Java

Tags: java, file, matrix

I have a big Matrix Nx2 - yes only two columns but thousand of lines) and I would like to create one file per "group" of lines. This grouping should be done by the columns which has a date.

My matrix is already sorted, but I'm struggling to create a file in which I will have each line representing a record from my former matrix

For example, I already have the following structure in a matrix:

```
 COL0  COL1
 1234   Environmental Sciences & Ecology
 1997   Chemistry; Mathematics; Physics
 1997   Science & Technology - Other Topics
 1997   Neurosciences & Neurology; Physiology
 2002   Dermatology
 2005   Biochemistry & Molecular Biology
 2005   Geochemistry & Geophysics
```

Each "date" (they are String in my code) will be a file with its respecting value(s). In that case, 1997 and 2005 will 2 lines each, one for each "repetition".

My question is, how to put every record (in separate lines) for each date. I ordered it in a attempt to make things easier but the didn't help

Any help would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Map<String, List<String>>` for collecting your data in groups by year.
Then you can iterate through the map and create file for each entry and write entry values into map.

Comment: Yeah, I have it by year, using Map, but the problem is that each  key (date) stores its values side by side. like: 1997 Chemistry; Mathematics; Physics, Science & Technology - Other Topics, Neurosciences & Neurology; Physiology.

I'm not very familiar with Map. Is it possible to retrieve each value separately per key to manipulate or once they are "stored" they become one big string ?

Comment: You can use Joiner from Guava lib. Example: Joiner.on("\n").join(map.get(key)). All your values will be separated by new line. Then write this string into created file.

Comment: Great ! I shall try this and let you now : ) - Thanks in advance.

Comment: I still did not try this alternative, but hopefully will do it tomorrow. Do you have an example of how to use it ?

This is the code that I'm using to "construct" my normal hasmap - in another comment

Comment: `public int Contruct_Hash_WOS(ArrayList<WOS_Class> al_wos_par) {

        for (int i = 0; i < al_wos_par.size(); i++) {
            if (!hash_features_wos_ti.containsKey(al_wos_par.get(i).getPY())) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add(al_wos_par.get(i).getTI());

                hash_features_wos_ti.put(al_wos_par.get(i).getPY(), list);
            } else {
                hash_features_wos_ti.get(al_wos_par.get(i).getPY()).add(al_wos_par.get(i).getTI());
            }}` @eg04lt3r, sorry for the bad format, it is terrible !